# Magento 2.1.6 - File permissions keep resetting some to none

Tags: magento2, permissions, file-permissions, magento2.1.6

So i run the necessary permission commands for my Magento installation, i then notice the permissions change by them self and some folders all of a sudden have no permissions set, for example in the /var folder, only a few have permissions set. Why would this happen?

Comment: because you have different users running commands

Comment: @MagenX will you elaborate your comment.

Comment: so hosting have php user, apache user, or even stack master user, like bitnami/daemon, etc, and then probably he logins as root and run his own commands... magento when execute scripts it will use php/apache user with permissions set in config file, etc.. we dont know his environment...

Answer (score 0):

Execute these commands to set the sticky bit:

```
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+s {} \;
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;
```

[Source](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2525#issuecomment-159898476)